# Не могу обратиться к переменной

Tags: android, kotlin

Создал метод для таймера

```
override fun showTimer(timeOut: Long) {
        val timer = object : CountDownTimer(timeOut, 1000) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                actionWarning.text = String.format(AppResources.getString(R.string.wait),
                        millisUntilFinished / 1000)
            }

            override fun onFinish() {
            }
        }.start()
    }
```

Но не могу обратиться к переменной **timer** в методе onDestroy()

Comment: пришла пора узнать что то про области видимости переменных наверное

Comment: Ваш код требует хорошего рефакторинга.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если Вам нужно обратиться к локальной переменной другого метода, то так врядли получиться)

Попробуйте объявить переменную в качестве поля класса.

```
private val timer: CountDownTimer
```

Comment: Это костыль, а не решение. По-хорошему код надо рефакторить.

Comment: Где вы увидели костыль?) в объявлении переменной? Если Вам будет легче, её можно сразу же и проинициализировать раз на то пошло.

Comment: не ваш код рефакторить, а автора. Объявление переменной класса само по себе Ок. Но в контексте кода автора, это костыль.

Comment: ну так автор хотел обратиться из одного метода к переменной другого метода.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja данный ответ мне помог, вроде как всё работает корректно.

Comment: @Inkognito, а что произойдет если вы случайно вызовите этот метод повторно, забыв остановить созданный первым вызовом таймер?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja в моей логики приложения такое невозможно)

Comment: @Inkognito, это вы сейчас так уверены. Через полгода будете доделывать-переделывать чего, и упс :)