# Как передать результат записанный в переменную из одной функции в другую Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

```
fun onClickResult1 (view: View) //когда нажимаешь на кнопку, записывается первый результат
{
    val a = getResult()
}

fun onClickResult2 (view: View) //когда нажимаешь на вторую кнопку, записывается второй результат, и из второго вычитается первый
{

    val b = getResult().toInt()
    val otvet = b - a
    binding.res1.text = otvet.toString()
} // как передать a из onClickResult1 в onClickResult2?
```

Comment: к чему привели собственные поиски решения? Задача не из ядерной физики, процесс описан в каждом учебнике. Да и на этом сайте примерно раз в неделю спрашивают.

Comment: не смог найти нигде понятного решения, другие похожие решения видел, но они не про это, можете хоть подсказать чем пользоваться для решения моей проблемы пожалуйста, я искал час везде и нигде не нашел ничего подходящего

Comment: я прямо на этой же странице в блоке похожих вопросов вижу вопрос с почти таким же заголовком

Comment: там нет ответа, там не используется binding

Comment: Ну и при чем тут вообще биндинг?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не могу обратиться к переменной](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/665120/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9)